# Perl Win32::API – dependent DLL not detected

Tags: c, perl

This perl script is modified from the @ikegami parallel arrays version to include test data.

On execution, it fails with this error message:

“The program can’t start because gsl.dll is missing from your computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.”

However, when a C program runs PolyFit it executes without error.  The source code for it follows the perl script below.

gsl.dll is present in the same directory as PolyFitGSL.dll,   D:/prjct/model/code/SRS1/binaries/:

[image: Thi is an image of the directory]

```perl
#  @ikegami parallel arrays version

use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw( state );

use Config  qw( %Config );
use Win32::API qw( );

use constant PTR_SIZE => $Config{ptrsize};

use constant PTR_PACK_FORMAT =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'L'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

use constant PTR_WIN32API_TYPE =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'DWORD64'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'DWORD32'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");
   
# local definitions
my $fitorder = 3;
my @XVals = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
my @YVals = (12.36,12.32,12.31,12.37,12.44,12.44,12.5,12.46,12.48,12.51);


Win32::API::Type->typedef('uintptr_t' => PTR_WIN32API_TYPE);

my $dll = 'D:/prjct/model/code/SRS1/binaries/PolyFitGSL';

sub get_buffer_addr { unpack(PTR_PACK_FORMAT, pack('P', $_[0])) }

sub poly_fit {
   my ($xvals, $yvals, $fitorder) = @_;
   @$xvals == @$yvals
      or croak("Mismatch in the number of X vals and Y vals");
            
   state $PolyFit;
   if (!$PolyFit) {
      my $adjusted_proto = '
         int __declspec PolyFit(
            int numPts,
            uintptr_t xVals,
            uintptr_t yVals,
            int fitOrder,
            uintptr_t coef,
            uintptr_t fitVals,
            uintptr_t rSquared
         )
      ';
      
      $PolyFit = Win32::API::More->new($dll, $adjusted_proto)
            or die("Can't link to PolyFit: $^E\n");
     }
     
   my $n = @$xvals;

   my $xVals     = pack("d$n",                 @$xvals);
   my $yVals     = pack("d$n",                 @$yvals);
   my $coef      = pack('d'.( $fitorder + 1 ), ( 0 )x( $fitorder + 1 ));
   my $fit_vals  = pack("d$n",                  ( 0 )x( $n ));
   my $r_squared = pack('d',                    0);
     
   my $rv = $PolyFit->Call(
      $n,
      get_buffer_addr($xvals),
      get_buffer_addr($yvals),
      $fitorder,
      get_buffer_addr($coef),
      get_buffer_addr($fit_vals),
      get_buffer_addr($r_squared),
   );

   # I'm assuming the return value indicates whether the call was successful or not?
   return if !$rv;
}

my ($coef, $fitVals, $r_squared) = poly_fit(
   \@XVals,
   \@YVals,
   $fitorder,
)
   or die("Error");
```

When provided with an input data file, this C program runs successfully, with no error executing PolyFit

```
lang-C

// PolyFitFileData.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "..\PolyFitGSL\PolyFitGSL.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ReadSingleColDataFile(const char* filename, int numPts, int numHeaderRows, double* data)
{
    int i;
    double curNum;
    char line[32];
    FILE* fPtr;
    fopen_s(&fPtr, filename, "r");
    if (fPtr == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (numPts + numHeaderRows); i++)
    {
        if (fgets(line, 32, fPtr) != NULL)
        {
            if (i >= numHeaderRows)
            {
                curNum = strtod(line, NULL);
                data[i - numHeaderRows] = curNum;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, n, resFit, lineNum;
    double* xVals;
    double* yVals;

    double* coef;
    double* estYVals;
    double* rSquared;

    FILE* fptr;
    int fitOrder=1;

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        printf_s("Pass in 4 args: \n(1) number of points \n(2) filename with data (Y values only, one per line, one header line)\n(3) Fit order\n(4) Output Filename (or empty string for none)");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (fopen_s(&fptr, argv[2], "r") != 0) {
        printf("Error! opening input file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(-16);
    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    fitOrder = atoi(argv[3]);

    xVals = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    yVals = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    if (fptr != NULL) {
        char line[100];
        lineNum = 0;
        while ((fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr) != NULL) && lineNum < (n + 1)) /* read a line from a file */ {
            if (lineNum > 0)
            {
                //then parse string and add double to list
                yVals[lineNum - 1] = atof(line);
                xVals[lineNum - 1] = (double)lineNum;
            }
            lineNum++;
        }

        fclose(fptr);
    }
    else {
        return -22;
    }

    coef = (double*)malloc((fitOrder + 1) * sizeof(double));
    estYVals = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    rSquared = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    resFit = PolyFit(n, xVals, yVals, fitOrder, coef, estYVals, rSquared);

    //I can print out results to file now here, or to screen....

    printf_s("Completed fit.  Result from PolyFit function was %d.\n", resFit);

    printf_s("Fit order: %d\n", fitOrder);
    printf_s("RSquared: %f\n", *rSquared);
    printf_s("Coefficients:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < fitOrder + 1; i++)
    {
        printf_s("[x%d] %f\n", i, coef[i]);
    }
    printf_s("%d Data points (x,y,yFit):\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf_s("%f\t%f\t%f\n", xVals[i], yVals[i], estYVals[i]);
    }

    //if you pass in empty string "" then assume that you don't want to write to disk
    fptr = NULL;
    if (strlen(argv[4]) > 2)
    {
        if (fopen_s(&fptr, argv[4], "w") != 0) {
            printf("Error! opening file for output");
            // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
            exit(-16);
        }

        fprintf_s(fptr,"Fit order: %d\n", fitOrder);
        fprintf_s(fptr, "RSquared: %f\n", *rSquared);
        fprintf_s(fptr, "Coefficients:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < fitOrder + 1; i++)
        {
            fprintf_s(fptr, "[x%d] %f\n", i, coef[i]);
        }
        fprintf_s(fptr, "%d Data points (x,y,yFit):\n", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fprintf_s(fptr, "%f\t%f\t%f\n", xVals[i], yVals[i], estYVals[i]);
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }

    free(coef);
    free(estYVals);
    free(rSquared);

    free(xVals);
    free(yVals);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Strawberry Perl? How did you install the GSL library? Can you provide a link to the parallel array version you are referring to?

Comment: How do you compile the C program?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, [This is the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64036239/589924)

Comment: Do you have better luck if you change the CWD to `D:/prjct/model/code/SRS1/binaries`? I don't really know anything about how Windows locates dependencies.

Comment: The gsl.dll error appears at the attempt to create the PolyFit function, and running in the binaries directory does appear to resolve that problem.  The perl script now dies on the attempt to call PolyFit but $^E provides no information on the nature of the error.

Comment: It's not that PolyFit returns an error but rather that the attempt to execute it fails.  Is there any way that Win32::API could provide information about the nature of the failure?   Or are there any theories that could be tested?

Comment: It can't. It's impossible. It has no way of knowing if or what was done wrong (short of memory access violations which would result in a debugable protection fault).  Maybe the function isn't `__cdecl` as you indicated but `__stdcall`? Anyway, the comments aren't the place for new Questions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Perl problem per say; this is about letting Windows know where to find your DLLs. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order).

The directory in which the script and thus the DLL reside can be obtained using

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
```

Among other solution, you'll find switching the current directory to that directory

```perl
chdir($RealBin);
```

and adding it to the PATH

```perl
$ENV{PATH} = "$RealBin;$ENV{PATH}";
```